# Get mean, stddev and max value from HSV image

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to calculate the Mean, Std and Max Value of hue, saturation and value of an image given in HSV colour space. I split it in three channels to calculate the maximum value of each channel. The problem is I am getting exactly the same value for each channel. The same for mean, std and maximum for hue, saturation and value. I think, maybe I am not understanding well what I get with the functions I am using. Here is my code:

```
Scalar mean, std;
meanStdDev(image, mean, std, Mat());
vector <Mat> HSV;
split(image, HSV);  
double MaxValueH, MaxValueS, MaxValueV;
minMaxLoc(HSV[0], 0, &MaxValueH, 0, 0);
minMaxLoc(HSV[1], 0, &MaxValueS, 0, 0);
minMaxLoc(HSV[2], 0, &MaxValueV, 0, 0);

colour farbe(mean[0], std[0], MaxValueH, mean[1], std [1], MaxValueS, mean[2], std[2], MaxValueV);
return farbe;
```

Comment: How is the Visual Studio bit in the title relevant? Also, what do the implementations of `meanStdDev`, `minMaxLoc`, `farbe` & `split` look like?

Comment: having `Mat()` in `meanStdDev` looks suspicious because that is used for a mask, I'd remove it.

Comment: I don't understand your question Jesper Juhl... Thank you for your advice vu1p3n0x but I have removed and still the same problem...

Comment: This code works well for me. Please be sure that the issue is not in the `colour` structure. Also be sure that `image` is actually an HSV image (have you used `cvtColor(..., COLOR_BGR2HSV)`?)

Comment: is `image` a HSV image?

Comment: @Miki I'll just ignore this question then. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, image is an HSV image. I will have a look a the colour structure again, just in case. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Are the elements of Scalar always of type double, or does the type change depending on something?